# get_option and list of options

Tags: options

I'm trying to retrieve some values stored in the option panel of WordPress, however the list of the [options I found](http://codex.wordpress.org/Option_Reference) on the site seems not complete.
Perhaps it's me looking in the wrong place.

What for getting the name of the author of a given post?

Answer (score 1):

Options are for general settings not specific to a post. To get the name of the author of a post, you will need to first get the ID of the author from the [`$post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post) object and then use that to create a [`$user`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User) object from which the name can be retrieved.

Example code:

```
global $post;
$user_id = $post->post_author;
$user = new WP_User( $user_id );
$display_name = $user->display_name;
$first_name = $user->first_name;
$last_name = $user->last_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Options Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Option_Reference) doesn't seem not complete, it is not complete. Have you seen the big notice in the page you linked?

Anyway, it you want to get the name of the author of a given post you are looking in the wrong place. The author of a post is not a option, i.e., it is not a preference or configuration setting. Instead, author is a [property of the post object](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post). You can get the author of a given post in various ways. For example, if you are inside [the loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) you can use [get_the_author()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author) function.

Example outside the loop:

```
 //get the $post object of the post with ID 54
 $post = get_post(54);
 //the author info (return a WP User object)
 $author_info = get_userdata($post->post_author);
 echo $author_info->display_name;
```